# Non-unique 2-factorization of 2k-regular graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Petersen proved that [every 2*k*-regular graph is 2-factorable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization#2-factorization).  The factorization is in general not unique.

> Given a 2*k*-regular graph, is it possible to move from any 2-factorization to any other 2-factorization by altering two 2-factors at a time?

If we broaden the question to multigraphs then the answer is no; consider the multigraph on three vertices with two edges between each pair of vertices and a loop on each vertex.  This suggests that the answer is no even for graphs.  In fact a colleague of mine suspects:

> The answer is no even if we change "two" to any bounded number

(where by "two" here I mean only the number of factors being altered simultaneously, not the "2" in "2-factor").  However, we don't know how to prove or disprove this.

The motivation for this question comes from a conjecture in representation theory but the connection is rather convoluted so I will omit the details here.

Answer (score 5):

No and in fact your multigraph construction is the counterexample. Just replace each edge with an "almost 6-regular" graph, like $K_7$ minus one edge, uv, and connect u and v respectively to the endpoints of the original edge.

Comment: Nice trick, thanks!  Any ideas about the followup question (replacing "two" with a bigger number)?

Comment: Let me counter-question - what is known about moving between 1-factorizations of regular bipartite graphs?

Comment: Good question!  I don't know, but this does seem to be a good place to start.  I'll try asking on the domino mailing list.